# PHP Regex issue getting required data

Tags: php, regex

I have been using PHP with a mix of strpos, substr and regex to manipulate a load of Strings, but I am having problems with it being perfect all the time.  The String I am playing with looks like this

```
string(63) "1*O#AY5523 F7 A5 J9 C9 D8 I1 W9 E4 LHRLAX-0935 1245 * 388 0E" 
string(63) "2*O#BA 3 F9 A9 J9 C9 D9 R9 I4 W9 LHRLAX-0935 1245 388 0E"
string(27) "US7080 INTL ONL CNX/STP TFC"
```

The data I am trying to obtain is

```
$this->terminalData[] = array(
    "flightNumber" => $fltcode,
    "from" => $ffrom,
    "to" => $fto,
    "seats" => $seats,
    "other" => $flightInfo
);
```

These are the things I know.

There will be many Strings of data but the lines I need always start with a number (so the first two strings above I want, the third string doesnt start with a number so it can be ignored)

The flight Number always has a preceeding #.  This is the part the messed up occasionally in my current code because I was using strpos but I dont know the length of the flightNumber.  The Flight Number always has 2 letters followed by 1-4 numbers.  There may be a space between the letters and numbers.  So in my two strings above the flight numbers are AY5523 and BA3.

From and To are always together, and consist of six uppercase letters (first three from, last three to).  So in the strings above from is LHR and to is LAX.

seats are always a letter/number combination followed by a space, so above they are all the F7 A5 J9 etc.

Other is all the additional data after the from and to e.g. US7080 INTL ONL CNX/STP TFC

```
//Get the String of data
$flightInfo = $elements->item($elNum)->nodeValue;

//Does it start with a digit?
if ( preg_match('/^\d/', $flightInfo ) === 1 )
{
    $pat = strpos($flightInfo, "#");
    $fltcode = substr($flightInfo, $pat+1, 6);
    $fltcode = str_replace(' ', '', $fltcode);

    $flightInfo = substr( $flightInfo, $pat+6 );

    $seatInfo = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z]{6,6}.*$/i', '', $flightInfo);

    $flightInfo = str_replace( $seatInfo, "", $flightInfo );
    $ffrom = substr( $flightInfo, 0, 3 );
    $fto   = substr( $flightInfo, 3, 3 );
    $flightInfo = substr( $flightInfo, 6 );

    while ( $elNum+1 < $elements->length && preg_match('/^\s*[A-Z][0-9\.\-]/i', $elements->item($elNum+1)->nodeValue))
    {
        $seatInfo = trim($seatInfo) . " " . $elements->item($elNum)->nodeValue;
    }

    $seatInfo = explode( " ", trim( $seatInfo ) );

    $seats = array();

    foreach ( $seatInfo as $si )
    {
        $seats[ substr( $si, 0, 1) ] = (int) substr( $si, 1 );
    }

    $this->terminalData[] = array(
        "flightNumber" => $fltcode,
        "from" => $ffrom,
        "to" => $fto,
        "seats" => $seats,
        "other" => $flightInfo
    );
}
```

I think it is nearly there, just need a little help making sure it always works.  My main problem at the moment is the way I make $flightInfo a substr of size 6, because I can't guarantee that the flight number will be this length.

So really my aim is to use more regex rather than substr etc.  I am also interested if there is an all together better way to split my strings up into the data I need.

Any advice on things appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
$str = '1*O#AY5523 F7 A5 J9 C9 D8 I1 W9 E4 LHRLAX-0935 1245 * 388 0E';
$reg = '~\d.+#([A-Z]{2}\s?[0-9]{1,4})\s(.+)\s([A-Z]{6})-([0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4})~';

preg_match($reg, $str, $matches);

$flight_no = $matches[1];
$seat_no = explode(' ', trim($matches[2]));
$from = substr($matches[3], 0, 3);
$to = substr($matches[3], 3, 3);

var_dump($flight_no);
var_dump($seat_nos);
var_dump($from);
var_dump($to);
```

You should be able to get 'other' data.

### Explained

```
~                 # opening delimiter
  \d.+            # match digit followed by any character one or more times
  \#              # match hash sign #
    (             # opening capture parentheses for flight info
      [A-Z]{2}    # match 2 uppercase letters
      \s?         # match space zero or one time
      [0-9]{1,4}  # match 4 digits consecutively
    )             # closing capture parentheses for flight info
  \s              # match single whitespace
  (.+)            # capture everything till space & uppercase char encountered
  \s              # match single whitespace
  (               # opening capture parentheses for from/to info
    [A-Z]{6}      # capture 6 upercase letters, from/to
  )               # closing capture parentheses for from/to info
  -               # match hypen which seperates from/to from time
  (               # opening capture parentheses for time info
    [0-9]{4}      # match 4 digits, depart time
    \s            # match single whitespace
    [0-9]{4}      # match 4 digits, arrival time
  )               # closing capture parentheses for time info
~x                # closing delimiter with free-space modifier 'x'
```

Note that I have used free spacing to comment the regex with 'x' modifier consequently having to escape hash sign in regex

Comment: Thanks, just testing this out and it seems to work great.  I have placed the preg_match in an if statement because if it didnt match it would stop.  Going to try testing this out now on more complex Strings.  If you get a chance later, would love an explanation because although I love regex, I find them difficult to create.